# Unreal Engine String Table not registered?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

the Is String Table Registered function always returns false with the name of my table as Id. I didn’t find anything on the web about it and doc Epic only talks about binding with flags
I need to use the String Table function for determinate language. Epic don't have doc for this, gpt 4 don't know too.

[what's i try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8VoJ.png)
[The Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eUgC.png)
[Working with the Flag (localise text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE692.png)